# py2app produces bundles that include all the libraries on my system

Tags: python, macos, py2app

Even for a simple print "hello world" python script, it produces a bundle of 72,5mb in size. Looking inside the script reveals that it seems to include all the Python and associated libraries installed on my system. I am using a no thrills setup file to generate a bundle.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Yes, disk space is cheap, but A 72,5mb executable for a hello world one-liner is totally unacceptable. Is there any way to fix this behaviour, considering according to the documentation it should include only needed libraries?

Comment: Sorry, what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Instead of cherry picking only needed libraries, it lumps every library into a bundle. Yes, disk space is cheap, but A 72,5mb executable for a hello world one-liner is totally unacceptable. Is there any way to fix this behaviour, considering according to the documentation it should include only needed libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution. The problem was caused by the fact I was using Python that came with Mac OSX.

I have reinstalled Python from Brew to a separate location and now py2app produces reasonably sized executables.